# Why Flash Player update requires Skype to close?

Tags: macos, flash-player

The version just updated is `11.8.800.97`. During the installation, the installer requires me to close Skype. Does the 2 software have any relationship ?

Note: I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `lsof` command in `Terminal.app`, looking for the case-insensitive string "flash", I see that the Skype process does have various Flash Player files open.

> ```
> [mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% lsof | grep -i flash
> Skype     18137 nevinwilliams  txt      REG                1,2     75208  7990910 /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player
> ```
>
> [similar results omitted]

It's common practice for upgrade installers to check to see what processes have opened files to the software being upgraded, and alert the user to any instances where applications may become unstable or lose data if a software component is modified while in use.

How exactly Skype is using Flash Player, I can only guess, but I've confirmed that Skype does indeed use the plugin, and so quitting Skype in order to let a Flash Player software upgrade proceed is necessary.

Comment: Most likely that the ads displayed within Skype may support flash based ads so they load the plugin in the event one is displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the scope of Flash is; it may be doing all of its animation, and perhaps even acting as a container for its video...?